# I want to extract month data from a datetime format column in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a data in format `01 Jan 19.00.00` (datetime), and I want to extract the month name only from it.

Tried the below code but getting output in numbers i.e. 1 2 3 and so on. I want the output either in Jan Feb mar format or January February march format.

```
data want;
  set detail;
  month = month(datepart(BEGIN_DATE_TIME));
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `MONNAME` format.

```
data test;
  dt = datetime();
  monname = put(datepart(dt),MONNAME.);
  put monname=;
run;
```

If you want "OCT" not "OCTOBER" you can add a 3 to the format (`MONNAME3.`).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the value in a report the better approach might be to use a date value formatted with `MONNAME.`

The values of a date formatted variable will be ordered properly when the variable is used in a `CLASS` or `BY` statement.  *If you had instead computed a new variable as the month name, the default ordering of values would be alphabetical.*

```
data want;
  set have;
  begin_date = datepart(BEGIN_DATE_TIME);
  format begin_date MONNAME3.;
run;
```